# Regex to match verses from Bible

Tags: php, regex

So, I have this text:

> \n
>
> Geneza 15:6\s\sAvram a crezut pe Domnul, şi Domnul i-a socotit lucrul
> acesta ca neprihănire.
>
> \n
>
> Geneza 12:2\s\sVoi face din tine un neam mare şi te voi binecuvânta; îţi
> voi face un nume mare şi vei fi o binecuvântare.
>
> \n

How can i split in **PHP** the string by REGEX by \n and \s\s to get something like this:

```
[
 0 => ['Geneza 15:6','Avram a crezut pe Domnul, şi Domnul i-a socotit lucrul acesta ca neprihănire.'],
 1 => ['Geneza 12:2','Voi face din tine un neam mare şi te voi binecuvânta; îţi voi face un nume mare şi vei fi o binecuvântare.']
]
```

So every verse is preceded and succeeded by a new line, and the verse is made by two parts: the reference then two spaces and then the verse.

Comment: please show us what you have tried ...

Comment: `^\n(.*)\s\s(.*)[\n\r]$` works on Sublime but not on PHP, this gets the WHOLE vers, and then i tought i could split it by \s\s

Comment: Are `\n` and `\s` **literally** in the string? Or are you just writing out the non-printable characters for us?

Comment: Just writing this for you to see, those are not **literally** in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: https://regex101.com/r/hD4nP8/1

```
/^(.+?)\s{2}(.+)$/gm
```

Comment: There is no /g modified in PHP, so I had to use preg_match_all /im, answer below

Answer (score 0):

Check this regex

```
[^\n]*?(.+?)  ([^\n]+)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nC7lL5/1)**

*PHP Code*

```
$re = "/[^\\n]*?(.+?)  ([^\\n]+)/"; 
$str = "\n\nGeneza 15:6  Avram a crezut pe Domnul, şi Domnul i-a socotit lucrul acesta ca neprihănire.\n\n\n\nGeneza 12:2  Voi face din tine un neam mare şi te voi binecuvânta; îţi voi face un nume mare şi vei fi o binecuvântare.\n\n"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what finally worked for me:

```
<?php
$handle = fopen('versete.txt', 'r');
$contents = fread($handle, filesize('versete.txt'));
fclose($handle);

preg_match_all('/^(.+?)\s{2}(.+)$/im', $contents, $matches);
echo '<pre>';
$final = [];
for($x = 0; $x < count($matches[1]); $x++) {
   $final[$matches[1][$x]] = $matches[2][$x];
}
var_dump($final);
```